# Deploy celery flower

Tags: django, celery, flower

I have deployed flower to monitor celery tasks, but the dashboard of flower don't show enough information. [image]

How can i get the full information dashboard as documents. 
https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/stable/screenshots.html

Comment: for a start, in the documentation the path is `/workers` and yours is `/flower`

Comment: No, this is subpath I have configed in nginx.

Comment: Hello,
Have you resolved this issue ? I have the problem and do not have any ideas.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Flower 0.8.4](https://pypi.org/project/flower/0.8.4/) is the latest version which looks the same as on the [screenshots](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshots.html)  . Since [flower 0.9](https://github.com/mher/flower/tree/0.9) templates *.html have changed and [workers](https://github.com/mher/flower/blob/0.9/flower/views/workers.py) view seems to be broken. This view should redirect to the worker name page. The [issue](https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/851) related to broken view has been already raised.

Comment: And the issue related to missing worker name link on the dashboard.html has been already raised (the same issue as you have): https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/860.